# Junit5 and mocking, null object

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to test a class when it is extending another class which requires me to define an implicit constructor.

```
public class MyCustomHandler extends SomeHandler {

   @Autowired
   private Object1 object1;

   @Autowired
   private Object2 object2;

   public MyCustomHandler (String name, ServicesManager servicesManager,
        PrincipalFactory principalFactory, Integer order) {
      super(name, servicesManager, principalFactory, order);
   }

   public boolean doSomething () {
     object1.foo();  // <- object1 is null here when testing
   }

   //Some other override methods
}

//Test class
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CustomAzureAuthenticationHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    Object1 object1 ;

    @Mock
    Object2 object2 ;

    @InjectMocks
    MyCustomHandler myCustomHandler;

   //Test methods
   @Test
   void doSomeTest() {
       when(object1.doSomething()).thenReturn(false);
       myCustomHandler.someMethod();
   }
 }
```

When a method from my real class is being called that is under test, it is making a call to `object1.foo()` and `object1` is `null`.

I understand this is probably due to not having a no-args/default constructor and it's using the implicit constructor that I'm forced to implement which is not creating my mocked objects. I just haven't been able to figure out how to get around this.

Comment: Since you are using a custom constructor, you should make sure that the required dependencies are properly injected when you create an instance of `MyCustomHandler`. Try using `@ContextConfiguration` in your testing configuration class to ensure that Spring injects the mocked objects into your `MyCustomHandler` when it's created.

Comment: Why are `object1` and `object2` not part of your constructor? Why mix constructor and field injection?

Comment: If collaborator/field `object1` is null, then mock-injection failed (maybe because no public setters for those fields). To exclude other errors, also you show the constructors of `Object1` and `Object2` and paste the error-message.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the inputs. I have got it to work by simply updating my constructor to accept objects(instead of autowire) the fields and passing in the objects thru my configurer classs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you mix constructor-based injection with field-based injection. I would recommend to move all dependencies to the constructor. You can then pass everything as required:

```
public class MyCustomHandler extends SomeHandler {
   private final Object1 object1;
   private final Object2 object2;

   public MyCustomHandler (
         final String name,
         final ServicesManager servicesManager,
         final PrincipalFactory principalFactory,
         final Integer order,
         final Object1 object1,
         final Object2 object2) {
      super(name, servicesManager, principalFactory, order);
      this.object1 = object1;
      this.object2 = object2;
   }

   public boolean doSomething () {
     object1.foo();  // <- object1 is null here when testing
   }

   //Some other override methods
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing based on your comment in original post. Thanks for posting the answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can use the @BeforeEach annotation to manually instantiate MyCustomHandler before each test, passing in the mock objects. The @BeforeEach annotation in JUnit 5 allows you to run some initializing code before each test.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CustomAzureAuthenticationHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    Object1 object1;

    @Mock
    Object2 object2;

    MyCustomHandler myCustomHandler;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // Manually instantiate MyCustomHandler with mock dependencies
        myCustomHandler = new MyCustomHandler("name", mock(ServicesManager.class), mock(PrincipalFactory.class), 0);
        myCustomHandler.object1 = object1;
        myCustomHandler.object2 = object2;
    }

    @Test
    void doSomeTest() {
        when(object1.foo()).thenReturn(false);
        myCustomHandler.doSomething();
        // Add your assertions here
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because the fields `object1` and `object2` of `MyCustomHandler` are private.